# Wordpress Multisite 404 error

Tags: wordpress, multisite

I hope you can help.

I've setup a wordpress multiste and use WordPress MU Domain Mapping. I run 10 sites using this system with no problem. However, the latest site is generating a 404 error when I turn the domain mapping on.

example.com/domain works

domain.com is getting the 404 error.

I have:

- Disabled all plugins
- Enabled WP_DEBUG and nothing shows up
- Changed the www. and non www. versions to be primary
- Changed theme back to twentythirteen
- Disabled functions.php
- Increased PHP memory limit in wp-config and htaccess

None of the above fix the issue.

Any other ideas would be much appreciated

Thanks
Mark

Answer (score 0):

Does all domains registered at the same registar?
You need to make sure you have right DNS settings.

Comment: Hi ITPAL24. They are all listed on the same register with the same nameservers. It does know where to look because it is the default wordpress 404 message. Thanks. Mark